# How can I read the data on a serial connection?

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial, serial-monitor

I have a serial connection to a solar inverter using a USB. Using a free serial device monitor I can spy on the connection and watch it read/write information.

The info my computer gets from the inverter can only be read and exported (to .xlsx) on their application. Their app has no automatic export functionality and no api. The end goal is to be able to export automatically without me touching the computer at designated time intervals. I'm trying to circumvent their app by reading the data myself, and saving it to .csv so I can do anything else that I want with it once I have it.

[What the serial monitor shows, top is read, bottom is write](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRVUI.png)

I can't seem to decode what its sending/recieving. And I also don't recieve anything when I send those same write messages. And when I'm just looping and trying to readline() I get empty bytes.

My code looks like this, though I have a few different iterations of it doing similar things like looping through every baudrate, stopbits, and bitsize option. As well as looping through the 5 different unique write messages I see in the monitor.

```
# Construct serial connection using baud and stopbit
serialPort = serial.Serial(port= "COM3", 
                                   baudrate=115200,
                                   bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                                   timeout=0,
                                   stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
        
while(1):
    serialPort.write('01 03 00 2D 00 2D 15 DE'.encode()) 
    serialString = serialPort.readline()
    if serialString.decode() != '':
                print(serialString.decode())
```

Any help or advice for what I'm doing is appreciated.

Comment: I think, instead of `'01 03 00 2D 00 2D 15 DE'.encode()`, you want `bytes.fromhex('01 03 00 2D 00 2D 15 DE')`!

Comment: Likewise, instead of `serialString.decode()`, I think you want `serialString.hex(' ')`.

Comment: "*... trying to readline() I get empty bytes*" -- It's obviously a binary message scheme (e.g. there is no text), so there are no "*lines*" to read. Typically there's a one or two byte value for message length. The 3rd byte of a read message could be a  (remaining) byte count followed by a checksum or CRC16. Messages seem to start with 0x01, which is also an ASCII `SOH`, a rather unimaginative choice IMO (i.e. small binary values occur too often in actual non-text data, so a value that might occur less often would make a `start-of-message`  byte more distinctive).